# How can I create/update a file to specific folder on google drive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

Good day,
Have somebody any working example - how to create/update a file in specific google drive folder?

Google drive API help topics has no explanation on it

As I understand I need to use .parent property to set a parent folder id but how can I get this id? And one more problem - I don't understand how to update a file. When I save the same file one more time to 'root' - I get two equal files in root folder

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439457/ios-how-to-upload-a-file-to-specific-google-drive-folder-using-google-drive-sdk/13444516#13444516 for specifying the folder.

Answer (score 0):

From the Google Drive API documentation -

> By default, newly created files and folders are added to the root folder. To create a folder inside a different folder, first retrieve the parent folder to get its ID; then you can use that ID to set the parents property on the new folder...

So, if you wanted to create a file in folder1/folder2/folder3 then starting at the root you need to retrieve the id folder 1 by executing `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/root/children` with the query "title=folder1"

```
GTLQueryDrive *query =
[GTLQueryDrive queryForChildrenListWithFolderId:@root"];
query.q=@"title=folder1";

then once you have retrieved folder1, you can access the `identifier` property and use that in your next query

GTLQueryDrive *query =
[GTLQueryDrive queryForChildrenListWithFolderId:folder1Obj.identifier];
query.q=@"title=folder1";
```

and so on until you have retrieved the object for folder 3 and then you can specify it as the parent attribute for your file creation.

As for updating an existing file, are you specifying `newRevision=false` in your q property on the update?  It defaults to true.